# Why is the Presence different in the newest Lucifer comic series?

Tags: vertigo-comics

So, I have just finished reading the new Lucifer comic series that was released recently. What I'm confused about is why the Presence (or Yahweh) is back in Creation, why he died, and why he's different. Maybe I missed something critical during my read, but his personality is a massive deviation from what it was during the original series, which is rather apathetic and neutral.

Answer (score 3):

The Presence is back for the same reason Lucifer is - they were attacked. As we learn, the attacker was

> Gabriel,

though he doesn't remember it. Most likely he was brainwashed into doing it, and there was a suggestion that someone from the Heavenly host was responsible.

I believe they were attacked using the sword of Azazel. Presence was killed, and tainted. It formed a chrysalis and started transforming to that thing. Lucifer was just hurt, but still had to come back, to seek assistance with finding out what happened and why did it.

As to who was behind this - we'll likely never know, as the 19th issue seems to be the last issue. It doesn't seem like it was planned to end so abruptly, but since no new issues have been published...